# R: how to rearrange elements in a string using Regex?

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a string which has encoded variable length elements separated by commas. For example: `|A!B!C,=!A!B,>!A!C,<A!C` and `|A!B!C,%!B!C,%!BC,%A!B,&AB`.

These strings hold 4 (`|A!B!C`,`=!A!B`,`>!A!C`, and `<A!C`)  and 5 elements (`|A!B!C`, `%!B!C`, `%!BC`, `%A!B`, and `&AB`) respectively.

The absolute order does not matter but for comparison of sets I would like to reorder the elements so that the same symbols come first, a potential order would be, `&`, `|`, `=`, `<`, `>`, then `%`.

This would lead the first string to be arranged as follows: `|A!B!C,=!A!B,<A!C,>!A!C`.

And the second string as: `&AB,|A!B!C,%!B!C,%!BC,%A!B`

Currently, I am accomplishing this through an element-wise `strsplit`, `order` `paste` recombination which is very slow.

I was hoping I could accomplish the same objective with something along these lines:

```
library(dplyr) 
"|A!B!C,=!A!B,>!A!C,<A!C" %>% 
  gsub("(\\&.*?,)|(\\|.*?,)|(\\=.*?,)|(\\<.*?,)|(\\>.*?,)", "\\1,\\2,\\3,\\4,\\5", .)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsure of how to do this with a regex, as it's a complex `search-and-replace` scenario. My initial thought would be along the lins of yours with splitting and adjusting.. and what I'm providing may have simply over-complicated and not actually solved your problem. I approached by thinking in terms of allowing different orders for the "reordering" of strings... so if it's of no help I apologize.

```
#' The idea is to rearrange a string by providing an ordering rule.
#' @param strs The string containing the original data
#' @param rgx_order The individual characters to create the rule provided
#' in the order of the desired output
#' @param rgx_sprint This is the rule by which all ordered chars 
#' should abide, ie for this example "A punctuation or char followed by
#' anything and stopping at either a comma, or a line ending but not
#' including the seperator"
#' 
f <- function(strs = NULL, rgx_order = NULL, rgx_sprint = "\\%s(.*?)((?=,)|$)"){
        vrgx <- sprintf(rgx_sprint, rgx_order)
        fx <- function(str){
            stringi::stri_extract_all_regex(
                str, vrgx, omit_no_match = TRUE, simplify = TRUE
            ) %>% as.character() %>% .[mapply(nchar, .) > 0] %>% 
                stringi::stri_join(collapse = ",")
        }
        sapply(strs, fx, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
}

> chars <- c("|A!B!C,=!A!B,>!A!C,<A!C", "|A!B!C,%!B!C,%!BC,%A!B,&AB")
> new_order <-  c('&','|','=','<','>','%')

> f(strs = chars, rgx_order = new_order)
[1] "|A!B!C,=!A!B,<A!C,>!A!C"    "&AB,|A!B!C,%!B!C,%!BC,%A!B"
```

Comment: Looks like what I was hoping for. I will benchmark it against my solution. Well maybe not, Not sure why it does not seem to work with`f(strs = "|ACB,%AB,|BA", rgx_order =  new_order)` or `f(strs = "%Ab#|ACB,%AB#>1ac", rgx_order = new_order)`.